# How can I make Dynamic Title for Windows Phone Application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dynamic, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, title

I am developing a multilanguage application but there is a problem. It is that my application's title must be with traditional language. For example; it must be Bilgi Yarışması in Turkish store, Brain Challange in other stores. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx
You will need to create a separate project for Language neutral dll that will support all the languages for your app title on Tile and its name on the store list.